# Is there a workaround for increasing GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm using a texture array to render Minecraft-style voxel terrain. It's working fantastic, but I noticed recently that `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS` is alot smaller than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`.

My textures are very small, 8x8, but I need to be able to support rendering from an array of hundreds to thousands of them; I just need `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS` to be larger.

OpenGL 4.5 requires `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS` be at least 2048, which *might* suffice, but my application is targeting OpenGL 3.3, which only guarantees 256+.

I'm drawing up blanks trying to figure out a prudent workaround for this limitation; dividing up the rendering of terrain based on the max number of supported texture layers does not sound trivial at all to me.

I looked into whether `ARB_sparse_texture` could help, but `GL_MAX_SPARSE_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS_ARB` is the same as `GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS`; that extension is just a workaround for VRAM usage rather than layer usage.

Can I just have my GLSL shader access from an **array** of `sampler2DArray`? `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` has to be at least 80+, so `80+ * 256+ = 20480+` and that would enough layers for my purposes. So, in theory could I do something like this?

```
const int MAXLAYERS = 256;
vec3 texCoord;
uniform sampler2DArray[] tex;
void main()
{
    int arrayIdx = int(texCoord.z + 0.5f) / MAXLAYERS  256
    float arrayOffset = texCoord.z % MAXLAYERS;
    FragColor = texture(tex[arrayIdx],
        vec3(texCoord.x, texCoord.y, arrayOffset));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to ditch array textures and just use a texture atlas (or use an array texture with each layer containing lots of sub-textures, but as I will show, that's highly unnecessary). If you're using textures of such low resolution, you probably aren't using linear interpolation, so you can easily avoid bleed-over from neighboring texels. And even if you have trouble with bleed-over, it can easily be fixed by adding some space between the sub-textures.

Even if your sub-textures need to be 10x10 to avoid bleed-over, a 1024x1024 texture (the minimum size GL 3.3 requires) gives you 102x102 sub-textures, which is 10'404 textures. Which ought to be plenty. And if its not, then make it an array texture with however many layers you need.

Arrays of samplers will not work for your purpose. First, you cannot declare an unsized `uniform` array of any kind. Well you can, but you have to redeclare it with a size at some point in your shader, so there's no much point to the unsized declaration. The only unsized arrays you can have are in SSBOs, as the last element of the SSBO.

Second, even with a size, the index you use for arrays of [opaque types](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Opaque_Type) *must* be a [dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression). And since you're trying to draw all of the faces of the cubes in one draw calls, and each face can have select from a different layer, there is no intent for this expression's value to be dynamically uniform.

Third, even if you did this with [bindless texturing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture), you would run into the same problem: unless you're on NVIDIA hardware, the sampler you pick must be a dynamically uniform sampler. Which requires the index into the array of samplers to be dynamically uniform. Which yours is not.

Comment: I don't follow that bleed-over is *easily fixable*; I'm using minification=GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR and maxification=GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR. I'm also using anisotropic filtering, and mipmaps. I thought 1-pixel padding reduces, but doesn't eliminate bleeding. F̶u̶r̶t̶h̶e̶r̶m̶o̶r̶e̶,̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶1̶-̶p̶i̶x̶e̶l̶ ̶p̶a̶d̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ ̶m̶i̶p̶m̶a̶p̶s̶?̶ ([with care](https://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping/), seems like it can)